# Sql = want to use make an inner join statement but not with tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I want to use the fact that on two tables `t1` and `t2` I can make an inner join with `on t1.colum1>t2.colum2` to calculate the maximum drawdown of a return vector. The problem is that an inner join is only possible with two stored databases or tables and I wanted to do it selecting just a part of the tables.

Is there any other possibility, I am totally new to sql and I can't find any other option?

Thank you

**edit**

before manipulating my inner join to be able to calculate my maximum drawdown I have to be able to make this inner join on a selection on the tables and not the tables themselves. So I followed Mark's advice but I am still getting an error.  Here is my query:

```
select * 
from (select * from bars where rownum <= 10 as x)as tab1
inner join (select * from bars where rownum <= 10  as y) as tab2
on tab1.x=tab2.y
```

The error is  `ora-00907 missing right parenthesis`

- additional information extracted from OP's message published as answer to this post. *

Comment: What's the structure of the tables?

Comment: Mark = that's an oracle db
outis = what do you mean exactly by structure? the tables I want to get a selection from have millions of rows and about 10 columns

Comment: Table structure (also called the "intension" or "schema") is the table meta-information; it includes the column names, column types, default values, foreign keys and other restraints. Basically, I want the statements that you used to create the tables (though the information doesn't need to be valid SQL).

Comment: outis I have all this at work, I will tell you tomorrow if you don't mind thank you :)

Comment: Sure. When you have the information, edit it into the question.

Comment: A heads up: read up on formatting posts: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (this help doc is also accessible via the orange question mark in the editor toolbar). In particular, indenting lines with four spaces will format them as code, which you'll probably want to do for the table schema and any SQL statements.

Comment: @iracema78280: I don't have an Oracle installation right now, but my guess is that your aliases are inside the parentheses but they should be outside. 'WHERE rownum <= 10) AS X'. As I said, I haven't tested this but from memory, the aliases have to be after the parentheses.

Comment: @iracema78280: what are the "as x" and "as y" supposed to alias?

Answer (score 7):

You can inner join on subselects too, you just need to give the subselects an alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS X) AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Y) AS T2
ON T1.X = T2.Y
```

If you post your non-working query, I can give you a better answer more tailored to your exact tables.

Comment: Hi Mark, I did this query, using an alias, but it returned me an error saying that the tables were not found

Comment: by the way i did this at work, is there a way to install something similar to dbartisan and download a database so I can train at home? thank you

Comment: Can you update the question to include your broken query that gives this error? It's a lot easier to figure out where you're going wrong if I can see how far you have gotten so far.

Answer (score 0):

(inner) join is not limited to whole tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got a definition of maximum drawdown from [an investment website](http://www.confidentstrategies.com/maximum-drawdown.htm) (thanks Google!).     So I think we need to calculate the percentage drop between the highest point in a graph and its subsequent lowest point.

The following query calculates the maximum drawdown on investments in Oracle stock over the last twelve months.  It joins the `investments` table to itself, with aliases to distinguish the versions of the table (one for the highest peak, one for the lowest trough).  This may not mirror your precise business logic, but it shows the SQL techniques which Oracle offers you.

```
select round(((max_return-min_return)/max_return)*100, 2) as max_drawdown
from
    ( select max(t1.return_amt) as max_return
             , min(t2.return_amt) as min_return
      from investments t1
           join  investments t2
           on ( t1.stock_id = 'ORCL'
                and   t2.stock_id = t1.stock_id
                and   t2.created_date > t1.created_date )
      where t1.created_date >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
      and t2.created_date >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
    )
/
```

This query will return zero if the stock has not experienced a drop during the window.  It also does not check for a following upturn (as I understand drawdown it is supposed to be the bottom of a trough, a point we can only establish once the stock has started to climb again).

With regard to training at home, we can download software from [Oracle TechNet](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html) for that purpose.  If bandwidth or disk space are an issue go for the Express Edition; it doesn't have all the features but you probably won't want them for a while yet.  Oracle do provide a free IDE, [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html).  As its name suggests it is primarily targeted at developers but it has many of the DBA-oriented features of DB Artisan.  For full-on database management Oracle offers [Enterprise Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28301/em_manage002.htm#sthref97).

**edit**

In the comments outis suggests

> You could add a `t1.return_amt >
>   t2.return_amt` in the join as a minor
>   optimization

I think it is unlikely that `return_amt` would be indexed, so I think it is unlikely that such a clause would have an impact on performance.  What it would do is change the behaviour for stocks which do not have a drawdown.  The query I presented returns zero for stocks which have increased continuously through the time window.  The additional filter would return a NULL in such a case.  Which is the more desirable outcome is a matter of taste (or requirements spec).

Comment: You could add a `t1.return_amt > t2.return_amt` in the join as a minor optimization.

Comment: As I look at it, I don't think the query will work, since `max(t1.return_amt)` might be from a different row than `min(t2.return_amt)`, which undoes the `t2.created_date > t1.created_date`. Instead, try a `max(t1.return_amt - t2.return_amt)` column in the inner select.

Comment: Since the default join is an inner join, wouldn't a stock with no drawdown result in an empty result set in the inner SELECT, rather than a row with NULLs, causing the outer SELECT to also have an empty result set?

Comment: @Outis - no because the query uses aggregate functions, which always return a row.